# Dividing arrays in Python for confusion matrix

Tags: python, confusion-matrix

I have an object, 2x2, and I want to divide it by a 2x1, such that the first component divides the first row, and the second divides the second row.
How can I do that?

```
cm = sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(Y1,Y2)
cm_sum = np.sum(cm, axis=1)
cm_perc = cm /  cm_sum.astype(float) * 100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to have the right dimension. The one you are dividing has to be a column vector. We use `.rehshape(-1,1)` to accomplish that.

```
a = np.array([[2,3], [5,6]])
print(a)
b = np.array([2, 4]).reshape(-1, 1)
print(b)
print(a/b)
```

#### Output

```
[[2 3]
 [5 6]]
[[2]
 [4]]
[[1.   1.5 ]
 [1.25 1.5 ]]
```

So your code then will be -

```
Y1 = [1,0,1,0]
Y2 = [0,0,1,0]
cm = metrics.confusion_matrix(Y1,Y2)
cm_sum = np.sum(cm, axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
cm_perc = cm / cm_sum
```

You could also use the `keepdims` argument in `np.sum` that will basically keep the dimensions and the output will be a column vector in this case. So -

```
cm_sum = np.sum(cm, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

will also work.

Comment: so simple! but perfect for my wantings. I spent so much time ! thank you !